# Can we "restart" regex from a certain position to rematch pattern?

Tags: regex

I have a text file which I want to parse.
I need to get all the texts inside tr("").

Below is the text. My regular expression matches first 3, but fails for the test4.
The test can be found here:
https://regexr.com/564gs

The problem with test4 is that I need to repeatedly match `\"([^"]|\\")*\"` until I end with `\"\)`
Is it possible to do something such as
`tr\( __REPEAT FROM HERE__ \"([^"]|\\")*\"(\)|(\s*\\)+\n\s*\+\s* __GO TO REPEAT__)`

```
// Regular expression: tr\(\"([^"]|\\")*\"(\)|(\s*\\)+\n\s*\+\s*), fails at line 6, stopped before first "

1 var test = tr("a simple one\\) \"right?")
2 var test2 = tr("")
3 var test3 = tr("another one")
4 var test4 = tr("god\"e mc'damn (yes) "        \
5                                                       \
6           + "[it's hard'] [what to do}]\\$&é\"'(-)'" \
7           + "third line?!")
```

If this is the wrong way to do it, any suggestion is much appreciated. I'm fairly new to RegEx.

Comment: Yes, but you need to fix yout pattern a bit. Something like `tr\("(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*"(?:\s*\\(?:\s*\+)?\s*(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*")?)*\)` [might work](https://regex101.com/r/bXTcYh/1).

Comment: @Paul and TheScientificMethod, your suggestions [will fail](https://regex101.com/r/wfYaLA/1) if there is a `")` in the string data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very true. I modified my answer. It should work now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! The `[^"\\]|\\[\s\S]` is outright genius.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind about the line separators and concatenators?

If not, just use `tr\(".*?"\)\s*\n` [regexr.com/564mm](https://regexr.com/564mm).

If yes, remove it using a second replacement regex afterwards. 
Check out this for the replacement:

`/("?\s+\\)|(\n\s*\+\s*")//gs` [regexr.com/564m4](https://regexr.com/564m4)

Comment: [This matches invalid input](https://regexr.com/564n2), though I'm not sure how important that is.

Comment: @HTNW Thanks for noticing! I do hope it's not important at all.

Comment: thanks for your input!  The regex is simple and elegant, but I need a tighter control.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Regex I finally use

`/ tr\(("(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*"(?:[\s\\]*\+\s*"(?:[^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*")*)\) /gm`

Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew. 90% of solution was by him )

I modified it slightly to fit my needs.